# C# - Creating 2 dimensional array from multiple datagridviews

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I am relatively new to c# and am having a problem filling a 2 dimensional array.

```
public string[,] myGridData = new string[50, 5];
```

The array data is contained in 7 datagridviews, each with 7rows x 5 columns.
I know how to get the data from the first grid, but am not sure how to loop through all 7 grids.

```
//Populate Array with data from grid 1  (7 rows,5 columns)
for (int rows = 0; rows < dgv1.Rows.Count; rows++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < dgv1.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col++)
    {
        myGridData[rows, col] = dgv1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have said you have 7 data grid views and that each has dimensions 7 x 5 I have removed some of the loop constraints and replaced them with constants. I wouldn't normally recommend that, but since you are using 2 dimensional arrays and you've specified the values it is the simplest way to go.

Here's the code:

```
var dgvs = new [] { dgv1, dgv2, dgv3, dgv4, dgv5, dgv6, dgv7, };

for (var i = 0; i < dgvs.Length; i++)
{
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 7; rows++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            myGridData[rows + i * 7, col] = dgv1[i].Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dkap - Then it is good practice to accept the answer as correct. Click on the tick below the number next to the question. Clicking the "up" triangle is good too. :-)